# "no matching function for call to" error while using inherited object in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm a C++ newbie. I have inherited one class in another, but I get an error message that says:

`error: no matching function for call to ‘Extended_queue::append(const Plane&)’`

What am I doing wrong? Part of my code follows below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "runway.h"

Runway::Runway(int limit)
/*
 Post:  The Runway data members are initialized to record no
 prior Runway use and to record the limit on queue sizes.
 */

{
    queue_limit = limit;
    num_land_requests = num_takeoff_requests = 0;
    num_landings = num_takeoffs = 0;
    num_land_refused = num_takeoff_refused = 0;
    num_land_accepted = num_takeoff_accepted = 0;
    land_wait = takeoff_wait = idle_time = 0;
}

Error_code Runway::can_land(const Plane &current)
/*
 Post:  If possible, the Plane current is added to the
 landing Queue; otherwise, an Error_code of overflow is
 returned. The Runway statistics are updated.
 Uses:  class Extended_queue.
 */

{
    Error_code result;
    if (landing.size() < queue_limit)
        result = landing.append(current);
    else
        result = fail;
    num_land_requests++;

    if (result != success)
        num_land_refused++;
    else
        num_land_accepted++;

    return result;
}
```

The error is on the line `result = landing.append(current);`
The header queue.h is referenced in runway.h. I've included queue.h below

```
const int maxqueue = 10; // small value for testing

struct Queue_entry {
    struct Queue_entry *next;
    struct Queue_entry *prev;
};

typedef struct Queue_entry    *queue_t;
typedef struct Queue_entry    queue_head_t;
typedef struct Queue_entry    queue_chain_t;
typedef struct Queue_entry    *queue_entry_t;

class Queue {
public:
    Queue();
    bool empty() const;
    Error_code serve();
    Error_code append(const Queue_entry &item);
    Error_code retrieve(Queue_entry &item) const;
protected:
    int count;
    int front, rear;
    Queue_entry entry[maxqueue];
};

class Extended_queue: public Queue {
public:
    bool full() const;
    int size() const;
    void clear();
    Error_code serve_and_retrieve(Queue_entry &item);
};
```

The code for runway.h is shown below

```
#include "plane.h"
#include "queue.h"

enum Runway_activity {idle, land, takeoff};

class Runway {

public:
    Runway(int limit);
    Error_code can_land(const Plane &current);
    Error_code can_depart(const Plane &current);
    Runway_activity activity(int time, Plane &moving);
    void shut_down(int time) const;

private:
    Extended_queue landing;
    Extended_queue takeoff;
    int queue_limit;
    int num_land_requests; //  number of planes asking to land
    int num_takeoff_requests; //  number of planes asking to take off
    int num_landings; //  number of planes that have landed
    int num_takeoffs; //  number of planes that have taken off
    int num_land_accepted; //  number of planes queued to land
    int num_takeoff_accepted; //  number of planes queued to take off
    int num_land_refused; //  number of landing planes refused
    int num_takeoff_refused; //  number of departing planes refused
    int land_wait; //  total time of planes waiting to land
    int takeoff_wait; //  total time of planes waiting to take off
    int idle_time; //  total time runway is idle
};
```

Runway.h references plane.h which is included below:

```
enum Plane_status {
    null, arriving, departing
};

class Plane {
public:
    Plane();
    Plane(int flt, int time, Plane_status status);
    void refuse() const;
    void land(int time) const;
    void fly(int time) const;
    int started() const;

private:
    int flt_num;
    int clock_start;
    Plane_status state;
};
```

Why does the compiler not recognise the methods inherited by Extended_queue from Queue?

Comment: `append()` takes a `Queue_entry`, and you're trying to pass it a `Plane`.

Comment: So what is a `Plane`?

Comment: @juanchopanza: I've updated the question to include Plane

Comment: did you tried declaring `Extended_queue landing;` in public scope?

Comment: But `append` doesn't take a `Plane`, as stated in the first comment.

Comment: `Plane` is not derived from `Queue_entry` so it cannot be appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you're passing a Plane object to

**Extended_queue::append(const Queue_entry &item)**

where **Extended_queue** is a child class of the parent class **Queue**.

1. You have not defined a version of Queue::append that can take Plane objects.
2. Or, you have not specified the class ***Plane*** to be a child of the class **Queue_entry**.

Either way, you are providing the wrong type of parameter to your function. It's like passing an *int* to a function that is calling for a *Plane*.